# Allow external connections XAMPP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Hello Im currently having an issue with my xampp sql server

> MySQL Error:SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'a2plcpnl0754.prod.iad2.secureserver.net' (using password: YES)

I all the information I have provided is correct but for some reason I cannot connect and Im assuming its because external connections are disabled by default on xampp. Any ideas?

Comment: I would hope that external connection are disabled. Beginners download and use XAMPP and it is for their and your protection that this is done

Comment: The `root` user ___is and should always be___ allowed to login ONLY from the PC running MYSQL Server for hughly obvious security reasons

Comment: Create a new user account. Set its permissions on a specific database. Then allow this new account to login remotely. If you cannot do this without help then you probably should not be trying to do this in the first place